# SQL Server Activity Monitor Ports

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, security, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to convince my IT department to grant me necessary [permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518.aspx#Security) on our SQL Server 2012 instance in order to use the Activity Monitor in the Management Studio.  Our lead IT administrator is concerned about granting them because he is unsure what, if any, ports Activity Monitor listens on.  I'd like to add that I currently have access to this SQL Server instance on port 1433.

I'm not very familiar with Activity Monitor's inner workings, are there any specific ports Activity Monitor listens on that should be a security concern?  Does anyone know any resources that may provide this information?  I want to make sure I give an accurate response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Activity Monitor, you connect on your instance's standard port. By default, this is 1433 for the default instance but this can be changed. In the activity monitor GUI, it is simply running SELECT statements against DMVs.

From a security perspective however, you will need to be granted the VIEW SERVER STATE permission, which has implications in its own right, and you ay get push back here. To see the processor usage, you also need OS permissions to perform. Otherwise the processor time graph will be greyed out.

Comment: Thank you Pete, this was informative.  Is this documented anywhere on the MSDN?  I'll have a look myself and see what I can find.

Comment: This link talks about the view server state requirement http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the ports for SQL server (normally 1433 for the standard instance, you can look it up in Sql Server Configuration Manager, SQL Server Network Configuration, Protocols for [Instance], TCP/IP) it is also neccessary to activate the firewall incoming "Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)" rule in the servers windows firewall configuration.